# How to add fake Credit Card Visa for Android pay?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-pay

I am developing an android application which uses android pay for the payment. In the https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-pay/#13 website. This is what the webiste write in the documentation "Tap the Buy button and select the fake Visa credit card from before." but there are no fake account that appear. I also follow other tutorials that they have this fake account.
Card Number: 4622 9431 2999 9901
Expiry: 12/17
CVV: 213

but after adding the address etc. android pay says it cannot add the credit card. How can I resolve this for developing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add some "fake"/sandbox card enable Sandbox Mode by executing following commands from command prompt/terminal:

```
adb shell
cd /sdcard/Download;
rm ­-f android_pay_env_override_*;
touch android_pay_env_override_sandbox;
```

Once done restart your phone and add following test credit card detail:

```
Card Number: 4622 9431 2999 9901
Expiry: 12/17
CVV: 213
```

After that for billing address you can use any valid billing address and your fake card will be ready to use.

I found one more detail on android pay github issue where one of the contributor mentioned that `You will need to add a real card to Android Pay, and then if you test your app using the sandbox you will not actually be charged.` Link to this comment: https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/issues/6#issuecomment-164813626

I am not sure if real card wont be charged when sandbox is enabled.

To revert from Sandbox to production execute following commands from command prompt/terminal:

```
adb shell
cd /sdcard/Download;
rm -­f android_pay_env_override_*;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I already tried the adb part but still, it keeps saying cannot accept the card, I reverted it to production again and tried to input a live credit card I hope this will not deduct some amount.

Comment: It wont deduct some amount if you are in sandbox mode. if you are in production mode it will charge you. And I would suggest you to add card only after changing to sandbox mode.

Comment: even if I setup this in my code? sorry I'm confused because in the developing side you can setup like this:


WalletFragmentOptions walletFragmentOptions = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                    .setFragmentStyle(walletFragmentStyle)
                    .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                    .setMode(WalletFragmentMode.BUY_BUTTON)
                    .build();


and I need also to implement the adb? in the android pay? sorry I'm confused.

Comment: As far as from my experience from last time I used it, you can use your card without being charge if device is in sandbox mode. I mentioned earlier that some contributor commented saying `You will need to add a real card to Android Pay, and then if you test your app using the sandbox you will not actually be charged.` I hope it is still true

Comment: I hope it will not, I tried to follow the braintree integration and there I can setup to Environtment test(sandbox) in the code of payment. But I don't know about Android Pay app, Do I need set up it to sandbox? or it's ok to that using the braintree code where in the Paymet I setup it to environment test(sandbox) and the Android Pay is not setup to sandbox? sorry that part is were I'm confused.

Comment: and also awhile ago adding a live credit card in the sanbox mode creates an error in the android pay I don't know why. but When I switch to live it is still ok

Comment: Actually, I am not 100% sure. but since you have setup sandbox in the code of payment I would assume it wont charge you anything.  you can give it a shot to find that out

Comment: haha ok thank you for sharing. I will try to revert it to sandbox mode again try to input the card and just hope it will accept the fake credit card but if it will not work I will go with the live one, again thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple. 100% working now

Step 1: Download and Install Namso CCGEN from play store.

Step 2: Open the app and enter the following details:-
Enter your Bin : 536595
Tick Data and CVV2
Quantity : 10
Formate : Checker
CCV2 : rnd
Month : Rnd
Year : Rnd

THis app is very useful in getting virtual card numbers.

Refer this article for step by step guide with pictures [How to Add Fake Mastercard Card on Google Playstore](https://www.techcool.in/2020/06/how-add-fake-mastercard-playstore.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in the Android Google pay documentation: [Join this User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data) with the same google account as you have on your device or emulator, and miraculously you will have a bunch of fake credit cards in your google account. Leave this group when you are done. Read more about it here:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite